# Installation of wstool and rosdep from source

Tags: ros, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build from source.  The instructions offered tell me to install the dependencies (python-rosdep, python-wstool, etc) using apt-get install.  First of all, I am not using a system with apt-get.  Secondly, I do not have root priveleges.  Is there somewhere I can download these packages and install them in a user or group directory?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52190/installation-of-wstool-and-rosdep-from-source/) by [BigBlueDart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3937/bigbluedart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The sources for the tools are at:

```
https://github.com/vcstools/  (You would need all of those, vcstools, rosinstall, wstool)
https://github.com/ros/rosdep
```

They can be installed from source using

```
python setup.py ... (options)
```

However using the pip based install is more convenient.

For installing python packages without sudo privileges, I recommend looking at the virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper projects, and then use pip as suggested in the other answer:

```
pip install -U rosdep
pip install -U wstool
```

However installing virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper nicely also requires root privileges, but those are packaged for most distributions, so maybe you can ask your admin nicely to install those if they are not already installed.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BigBlueDart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3937/bigbluedart/) on 2013-01-15**:
The virtualenv thing looks to be working for some things.  I've got rosdep and wstool installed.  However, I can't figure out how to initialize rosdep.  Can that be done without root?

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-18**:
I don't know. Open a new question for that, please.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm not in exactly your situation, but maybe I can help.  I needed to install from source as well without using apt because I was on an ARM board that isn't supported by ROS's apt repositories... though I did have root.  What I did was to follow the instructions for installing rosdep using pip:

```
sudo pip install -U rosdep
```

and just do the same for wstool.  To get around the not-having-root issue, use the '-E ' command line parameter in pip to have it install somewhere you can access. Of course, you'll also have to drop the 'sudo' in front. You'll still have to deal with path issues probably, but at least you'll have the tools.

---

Originally posted by [jeskesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3965/jeskesen/) with karma: 31 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3